# Why is my code implementing the Fisher scoring algorithm failing to converge?

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, glm, newtons-method

```
# Set data sets
data <- MASS::birthwt
X <- as.matrix(cbind(1, data[, -1]))
Y <- data[, 1]
n <- dim(X)[1]
p <- dim(X)[2]    
beta <- rep(0, p)  # Initialize beta
beta1 <- rep(1, p)  # Initialize beta1


# fit logit regression using Fisher scoring
while (sum(abs(beta - beta1))  > 0.01) {
  beta1 <-beta

  # Calculate mu and eta
  eta <- X %*% beta1
  mu <- exp(eta) / (1 + exp(eta))

  # Calculate the derivatives
  dmu_deta <- exp(eta) / (( 1 + exp(eta)) ^ 2)
  deta_dmu <- 1 / mu + 1 / (1 - mu)

  V <- mu * (1 - mu)  # Calculate the variance function
  W <- diag((dmu_deta ^ 2 / V)[,])  # Calculate the weight matrix
  Z <- eta + (Y - mu) * deta_dmu  # Calculate Z

  beta <- solve(t(X) %*% W %*% X) %*% (t(X) %*% W %*% Z)
}
```

I am using Iteratively Reweighted Least Square method. The `X` and `Y` come from the built-in dataset `birthwt`. I do not understand why this method does not converge. It always returns a `NaN`. But when I remove the intercept, it converges. I know that I can simply use `glm`, but I would like to understand the implementation.

Comment: Seems like `glm` don't converge either.

Comment: Can you provide where you get the formula for the IRLS? I've not `dmu_deta` nor `deta_dmu` in the one I use. Although it doesn't converge either.

Comment: @F.Privé [link](http://www.ciencias.unal.edu.co/unciencias/data-file/user_35/file/Modelos%20Lineales%20Generalizados%20-%20Clarice%20Demetrio.pdf) On the 23rd page. My professor doesn't like to write a powerpoint so I just picked one on the internet. The dmu_deta is the partial derivative mu to eta. I think glm also converges. At least I get some numbers rather than NaN.

Comment: See page 121(140) of [this PDF](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf).

Comment: @F.Privé It turns out that my data pre-prosessing has some problems. Thank you anyway! glm did not work actually, but I am curious why R can still produce the answer.

Comment: I think `glm` stops before going nuts (returns the iteration before). And it gives you a warning to say that there was a convergence problem. Can you make an answer giving the reason why this wasn't working?

Comment: @F.Privé I think it is because I treated non-numeric variable as a numeric variable.Just :race <- factor(race, label=c("white", "black", "other"))